# How to integrate OAuth2.0 login in electron

Tags: oauth, electron

I am newbie to electron and I am currently trying to implement an OAuth2.0 API which requires a callback URI. Url callback requires valid URL (https://myserver.com/sucess). so i tried this code snippet but does not work.

```
// Your GitHub Applications Credentials
var options = {
    client_id: 'your_client_id',
    client_secret: 'your_client_secret',
    scopes: ["user:email", "notifications"] // Scopes limit access for OAuth tokens.
};


app.on('ready', () => {

// Build the OAuth consent page URL
var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false, 'node-integration': false });
var githubUrl = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?';
var authUrl = githubUrl + 'client_id=' + options.client_id + '&scope=' + options.scopes;
authWindow.loadURL(authUrl);
authWindow.show();

function handleCallback (url) {
 console.log(url);

}

// Handle the response from GitHub - See Update from 4/12/2015

authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (event, url) {
  handleCallback(url);
});

authWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request', function (event, oldUrl, newUrl) {
  handleCallback(newUrl);
});

// Reset the authWindow on close
authWindow.on('close', function() {
    authWindow = null;
}, false);
});
```

also, i used angular js route but does not work either.

so I'm wondering if there is a way to run server inside electron app to serve app from URL (https://localhost:3000) and if so how this will affect app behavior at packaging and distributing time, i means does the app will run from the same port 
... any suggestions will help about how i can approach this problem. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue last week, i needed to integrate my electron app with vkontakte api which uses form of OAuth protocol. What you can do: 
1) You launch local node http server, probably in separate process as i did.
2) You request code through oauth link and set redirect uri as http://127.0.0.1:8000/, for some reason https://localhost didn't work for me.
3) In main process you wait for message with code from server, on server implemented corresponding logic (when you receive request and code in it send through process.send back to parent message with code)
4)You request access token from main process, you shouldn't change redirect_uri. You again catch response from your server.
5) You get access_token, you kill server... 
But when i did all this i read their docs till end and there was stated that standalone apps, like mine for desktop could receive token in easier way through "implicit flow", and you can get your token with only one call. Hope my experience could be extrapolated on your issue. Good luck!

Comment: can you please tell me how to integrate with "implicit flow", as per my understanding it is also required redirect uri that must not be file(://...)  protocol

Comment: @shivshankar did you figure out how to use the implicit flow, or did you solve this in another way?